# How to install a certificate to Work Profile user

Tags: multi-user, certificates

I would like my app on Work Profile user (https://www.android.com/intl/en_us/work/) to connect to a server with a cert.
Since Work Profile user shares Settings with Owner user, I installed a cert from the Settings (Security -> Install from internal storage/SD card). My app of Owner connects to a server with a cert correctly, but for Work Profile, it cannot.

Would you please tell me how I should do in order to make Work Profile recognize a cert?

Environment : Android 5.x on Nexus5 / 9

Answer (score 3):

### [Related: Android 10 and 11 CA Cert on Work Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73062105/13883950)

---

To install a user ca certificate into work profile you will need root access.

#### Installing user certificates into work profile:

1. Install an exported certificate normal way
2. Get a root shell

```
adb root; adb shell
```

3. Verify certificate and hash is installed.

```
# an example would be 1000_CACERT_*
ls /data/misc/keystore/user_0/<CACERT>
```

```
# example: 81c450f1.0
ls /data/misc/user/0/cacerts-added/<xxxxxxxx.0>
```

4. Move them to the work profile

```
cd /data/misc/keystore/
mv user_0/<CACERT> user_10/
```

```
cd /data/misc/user
mkdir 10/cacerts-added
mv 0/cacerts-added/<xxxxxxxx.0> 10/cacerts-added/
```